# Why PCA9306 2.9V coming at lower side even after removing the pullup

Tags: analog, i2c, level-shifting, analog-switch, level-translation

Below is my schematic for PC9306. The high side is connected to 5V and it is going to an Arduino Nano.

SDA from our ASIC is coming to J113 (SMA connector marked in RED). The voltage at this side is 2.9 V.

I removed all the pull ups connected to SDA.

5V side is R3, R4, R5 and low voltage side is R6, R7, R8.

What I observed is even after removing the pull ups from both side the lower side am observing a voltage of 2.9V at SD1 lLow voltage side).

May I know why?

[image]

Comment: What else is connected? If you remove all pull-ups, is the high voltage side of SDA at some voltage, is it 5V from Arduino, or floating, or what? Are there pull-ups inside Arduino or ASIC? Or on boards?

Comment: Yes high side of the SDA is from Arduino and it is 5V.Inside ASIC no pull ups.I read that Arduino has weak pull ups that can vary from 30K to 50K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circuit formed by the reference MOSFET, the connection between EN and VREF2, and the 200 kΩ resistor, regulates the voltage at the gates (EN) to V<sub>GS(TH)</sub> above Vref_A. This means that all MOSFETs conduct only for voltages between 0 V and Vref_A, i.e., higher voltages coming from the B side are clamped to Vref_A.

[image: LSF010x/PCA9306 internal schematic]

See the [application note](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/slva675) for this device.

Answer (score 0):

Since the 5V side of SDA is 5V, and the the enable pin EN is also pulled high to 5V, the level shifter FET in the chip used as a pass gate inside the chip will conduct.

Comment: Will I get 2.9V at SDA low side.If you don't mind could you please explain with a diagram.

Comment: Even after removing the SDA from arduino I observed 2.9V at lower side

Comment: Is the chip damaged? How much current flows if you pull the 2.9V SDA low?